# Excel 2013 auto disables Enable Fill handle setting

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have Windows 7 64 with MS Office 2013 64 bit. I notice that in Excel 2013, randomly after a few days or so, the setting that was previously enabled 'Enable fill handle and cell drag and drop' automatically disabled itself.

Strange but true, so I need to go into options and re-enable it again and again in order to drag down contents from one cell to another.

Is this a bug or somehow expected behavior of this settings? Can it be enabled once for all?

Also to mention, this is Corporate Office PC, I don't have administrative privileges and on my own can not control office updates.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, is there possibility of anyone else using your computer? Is the answer is *absolutely* no? When this start happening?

Comment: It's absolutely no. The office PC is secured by domain username password and no other user can use it. I guess it has started after Office 2013 was installed by the admins. First of all Dragging cells down did not work, so I found that setting was unchecked, I set it back and every now and then it auto resets to Unchecked state.

Comment: Does this option reset after a restart, or after closing and opening excel?

Comment: Well I need to keep a watch for that, but I guess it's happening after some random restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been facing the same issue for multiple years now, I think I've found the answer.
Rajeev, from your name I'm guessing that you might be Indian and that you file your taxes every year using form ITR1. The Excel sheet that you download from the income tax department of India contains a macro that disables the fill handle. Each time you open the sheet, it will reset that setting in your Excel options.
Man, it took me time to figure this out on my end.
I hope it helps!

Comment: What you mentioned  is absolutely right Longtarin. It's the Excel sheet released by Income tax Department of India that is disabling this option every time I open it. I verified it today and it's very true! Just after opening the sheet, the Fill Handle option gets unchecked.

Comment: This is so accurate!!!